# Creating an object and using it in another

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, include, mysqli

I am fairly new to object oriented programming. I made this class which connects to mysql database to be called from models. Is there any way i can include 'database.class.php'(my db class file)
in index.php, make it global and then access it from any object like so

```
$object = new object;
$object->dofunc();
```

Also another question is dofunc() expects an array for argument, how do i make this array also global so it can be accessed from ANY where!

Here is my db class

```
<?php

class Database {

    private $db;

    public function connect($config) {
        if (is_array($config)) {
            extract($config);
            $db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
            if ($db) {
                echo "balbabla";
                if (mysqli_select_db($db, $database)) {
                }
                else {
                    throw new exception("<br/><strong>Could not connect to $database under $host</strong>");
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new exception("<br/><strong>Could not connect to mySQL database! Please check your details</stromg>");
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Also this is the file that contains the array

```
<?php

//Configuration for the MVC Framework
$_SETTINGS = array();

//Routing settings!

//Default controller(This controller will be loaded if there is none mentioned in the URI)
$_SETTINGS['default_controller'] = 'User';
//Default method(This will be the default method run if no method is mentioned in the URI)
$_SETTINGS['default_method'] = 'Register';

//Database settings
$DB_SETTINGS['host']     = 'localhost';
$DB_SETTINGS['username'] = 'root';
$DB_SETTINGS['password'] = 'foobar';
$DB_SETTINGS['database'] = 'freelance';
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way i can include 'database.class.php'(my db class file) in index.php, make it global

You can, but you shouldn't.

> Also another question is dofunc() expects an array for argument, how do i make this array also global so it can be accessed from ANY where!

Again you shouldn't.

[Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you link me to a tutorial?

Comment: @LukeNukem Check out [the tutorial I am writing](https://gist.github.com/2362466) (in progress).

Answer (score -1):

To access a global variable from within a function, use the `global` keyword. For example, to access $DB_SETTINGS from `Database::connect()`, you could do:

```
public function connect() {
    global $DB_SETTINGS;
    ...
```

The array would then be accessible inside that function.

As for globally accessible classes, they are automatically just that. Defining a class makes it available anywhere.

Comment: i have to include it in an existing object with spl_autoload or include :\
I want to load it in the index.php for example and then use it any classes i use. I hope you get what i mean